# Call db from async method

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, asynchronous

I have a Controller that must accept a request and do not wait for the finishing of the processing,  give a response.

```
 @PostMapping
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
 public void processEvent(@RequestBody RequestMyObjectDTO requestMyObjectDTO) {
    MyProcessor.process(requestMyObjectDTO);
 }
```

After I give a response, I must execute the processing.

```
@Async
public void process(RequestMyObjectDTO myRequestObject) {
List<TestObject> testObjects= repository.findAllTestObject();
if (testObjects.isEmpty()) {
    return;
}
  .............
```

Is there any difference in where I will go to the database, in the asynchronous method, or outside it? In my case in Controller for example.

How it will impact behavior and what approaches are better?

Given that I need a check:

```
  List<TestObject> testObjects= repository.findAllTestObject();
    if (testObjects.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
```

At the same time, I expect that the controller may receive millions of requests.

Comment: Ofcourse there will be a difference. The latter is async, if you do it in your controller it is sync. So obviously there is a difference.

Comment: How it will impact behavior?